# Java alternative to SQL Server 2008 - Compact

Tags: c#, java, sql, database

I am looking to get started with SQL development and as such have decided to implement an application in both Java and C# that makes use of an SQL based database, in particular it will be a desktop application that stores certain types of data on the user machine through the database.

After reading the answer posted here: [C# local database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1121917/c-local-database-i-need-some-examples) I have decided to use [SQL Server 2008 - Compact](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/compact.aspx) for the C# version and now I am looking for a suitable alternative for the Java version.

Following on from [another post in Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3243466/java-local-databases/3243480) a user has recommended [Apache Derby](http://db.apache.org/derby/) and [H2](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html).

Would they be a suitable option for the Java application? The SQL 2008 Compact boasts how it's well suited for desktop application development, I don't want to have to install a bundle of software just to persuade Java to use "localhost".

I hope i've provided enough information, feel free to ask for anything inparticular.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered [sqlite](http://www.sqlite.org/)? You could easily use it for both Java and C#. It's nice and compact and pretty easy to work with. [Here's a discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41233/java-and-sqlite) of using it with Java.

Comment: Sorry, I have to disagree. While sqlite might be a perfect choice for creating desktop applications, it's a bad one for getting started with SQL development. For that task, a "real" SQL database would be a better choice.

Comment: "in particular it will be a desktop application that stores certain types of data on the user machine through the database." A "real" SQL Database is not suited to that environment. You'll be adding significant overhead that's inappropriate for the problem you're actually trying to solve.

Comment: I want to use the database so I can have the relationship between each piece of data. I did think about using XML but i'm not sure it would be suited to my needs,

Comment: XML? Nobody is talking about XML. SQLite is a full SQL database in a local file. You can do queries, have multiple tables, run most of your normal SQLesque commands just fine.

Comment: I don't understand, I assumed your comment was related to the structure of my data. You say I'm adding significant overhead but how would that be possible if I used SQlite? Surely it's designed for the desktop environment in mind...

Comment: @Axel was saying that sqlite was inferior to "real" SQL alternatives like PostgreSQL, MySQL, Microsoft SQL or Oracle. I was disagreeing and saying that those heavier databases were inappropriate for a desktop application because they balloon your requirements.

Comment: No, I didn't mean to say it's inferior per se. The important part in the original posting is this: "I am looking to get started with SQL development".

Answer (score 0):

Why not use SQL Server 2008 also for the Java application? I recommend [jTDS JDBC Driver](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, go with derby. All you have to do is include the jar file into your project and start a database connection like this:

```
// load database driver
String user = ...;
String password = ...;
String driver = "org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver";
Class.forName(driverName, false, this.getClass().getClassLoader());

// connect to database (replace DBName with your database name)
String url = "jdbc:derby:DBName;create=true;collation=TERRITORY_BASED"

Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("user", user);
props.put("password", password);

Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, props);
```

Then use the connection.